# How to change space between bars when drawing multiple barplots in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am drawing multiple barplots using the following DataFrame.plot call:

```
df.plot(kind='bar',
         stacked=False, 
         figsize=figsize,
         rot=0,
         alpha=0.5, 
         width=width)
```

However, I want to increase the size between the bars within each category. How can I achieve this?

[image: Current Output]

Comment: Hmm, an ugly way would be to increase the edge width: `df.plot(kind='bar',
         stacked=False, 
         figsize=figsize,
         rot=0,
         alpha=0.5, 
         width=width, linewidth = 4)` or similar

Comment: Sorry do you mean the "space" between the bars within each group or the size (width) of the bars?

Comment: @FabioLamanna my understanding of this is the width between each individual bar, the OP is already passing `width` param which would increase the spacing between each group

Comment: @kyrre what's the colormap you're using here? looks great!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define an edge around your bars and change its width:

```
df.plot(kind='bar', edgecolor='white', linewidth=3)
```

It works if you want to change the **space between bars within a group**.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be worth the trouble fixing it with df.plot() when they don't provide an argument to do that. If you don't insist on pandas.plot you could achieve your goal easily with Plotly. By modifying bargap=0.2,bargroupgap=0.5 you could adjust until the desired result is achieved.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

animals = ['snail', 'pig', 'elephant',
     'rabbit', 'giraffe', 'coyote', 'horse']

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
x=animals,
y=[0.1, 17.5, 40, 48, 52, 69, 88],
name='speed',
marker_color='red'
))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
x=animals,
y=[2, 8, 70, 1.5, 25, 12, 28],
name='lifespan',
marker_color='blue' 
))

# Here we modify the tickangle of the xaxis, resulting in rotated labels.
fig.update_layout(barmode='group', xaxis_tickangle=-45,bargap=0.2,bargroupgap=0.5)
fig.show()
```